# How do I funnel all my EC2 apache logs to one server

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, log-files

Is the best way to get all my EC2 Web Server Instance Apache Logs in one place, to create a "LogServer" EC2 Micro instance and point all the Apache Configs to it?  Not sure how to do this and wondering if anyone can offer help on doing this.  Do I need to do this via Syslog?

Comment: The fact that you're running on EC2 doesn't really play into things here. You'd implement central logging the same way on EC2 as you would if you were running your own physical servers.

Comment: Eight years later... the best option is often to push your logs to AWS Cloudwatch Logs using the Cloudwatch Agent.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via syslog and having a log server sounds fine to me. For how to do this I would suggest reading around as this is a very common issue, you can start here:
[Apache remote loggin](http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/sysadmin/2006/10/12/httpd-syslog.html)

Comment: That is the one article I've already read.  For someone with no prior Syslog or Apache.log experience...other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use syslog 
if you wish to roll your own, one way is to exploit the pipe, like this

```
CustomLog "| /usr/sbin/rotatelogs /var/log/httpd/access_log.%Y-%m-%d-%H_%M_%S 86400"
```

In this example, apache access log is being piped to a file through rotatelogs utility (see the '|' at the beginning). You can replace it with your own script that streams the log to where ever you like.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  We are thinking we need the logs to write directly, line by line...in real time because of autoscaling on AWS...we could be taking down and bringing up web servers at any moment.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using **SystemD** based Linux, Rsyslog is better suitable in this situation :

**On the central log server**

Allow the server to receive logs from the clients on port **514** via **udp** by uncommenting the above lines on */etc/rsyslog.conf* :

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
```

**On the clients**

Allow the clients to send **apache** error,access,agent & ssl logs to the central server by editing **apache** configuration file */etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf* :

```
ErrorLog  "|/usr/bin/logger -i -t httpd-host1 -p daemon.warning --server syslog.example.com --udp"
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/logger -i -t httpd-host1 -p daemon.info --server syslog.example.com --udp" combined
```

P.S : Use any tag for the facility to differentiate the logs received from different clients. Here i have used **host1** as a tag.

Restart httpd on the clients :

```
systemctl restart httpd
```

On the central log server and clients, restart rsyslogd :

```
systemctl restart rsyslog
```

Check the logs on the central log server :

```
 grep 'httpd-host1' /var/log/messages
```